# C ++: Cannot I assign values to a variable in header file?

Tags: c++

***header.h***

```
int m_linkinfo;
m_linkinfo = 1;
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Failed, with many errors. But if I commented the line `m_linkinfo = 1;`, everything is OK. Why? Cannot I assign values to a variable in header file? But If I changed the **header** file to the only one line: `int m_linkinfo = 1;`, The program is compiled successfully! Why? Is it different from the two lines of code above?

Comment: You should also be aware that if you include `header.h` in more than one source file, you will have multiple conflicting *definitions* of `m_linkinfo`. The solution is to *declare* `extern int m_linkinfo;` in `header.h` and *define* `int m_linkinfo = 1;` in a source file, e.g., `linkinfo.cpp`.

Comment: Choose C or C++, not both. Despite their similarities, they're different beasts. Since you had a CPP file, I've assumed you wanted C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't. That's a piece of *code* so it needs to exist inside a function of some sort, such as:

```
int main () {
    m_linkinfo = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You can, as you have seen, *initialise* it with:

```
int m_linkinfo = 1;
```

however, since that's allowed by the standard.

Keep in mind that it's often risky to *define* things in header files. By define, I mean statements that create things as opposed to those that simply notify the compiler than things exist (declaring).

That's because including the header in two different translation units can result in two copies of a thing with the same name and, if you subsequently try to link them together, you'll run into trouble.

The best way to solve that is to *declare* things in header files, such as:

```
extern int m_linkinfo;
```

and define them in a non-header (eg, CPP) file:

```
int m_linkinfo = 1;
```

That way, every translation unit that includes the header knows about `m_linkinfo` but only the CPP file creates it.

Comment: I'd just add that while defining variables and functions in headers is indeed risky as you say, defining classes there is absolutely normal and necessary.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't allow code outside of functions. In your example:

```
int m_linkinfo;
m_linkinfo = 1;
```

The second line is illegal, since it isn't in a function.

Outside of functions you can only declare or define variables and functions (or give directions to the preprocessor).

However, you are allowed to initalise a variable when you define it, so you can do this:

```
int m_linkinfo = 1;
```

which is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment is a statement. Statements are only allowed in functions. The line in the header file is not in a function. Therefore it cannot work.